# Strange behaviour of File Connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have the below flow

```
<file:endpoint 
    name="StartPoint" 
    path="C:\input" 
    pollingFrequency="5000" 
    doc:name="File"/>


    <flow name="fileUploader" doc:name="fileUploader">

        <quartz:inbound-endpoint 
        jobName="myServiceJob" 
        repeatInterval="5000" 
        doc:name="Quartz" 
        responseTimeout="10000">

            <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
        <quartz:job-endpoint ref="StartPoint"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
       </quartz:inbound-endpoint>       

    <!--<object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/> -->

     <file:outbound-endpoint 
        path="C:\outputfile" 
        responseTimeout="10000" 
        doc:name="File"/>

    </flow>
```

Now suppose, I have some files say (1.txt,2.txt, myimg.jpg etc.) in the "C:\input".

[image]

While I run the flow, though the file transfer happens to the destination folder "C:\outputfile", but the file are getting converted  to dat files.

[image]

So what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Mule is naming the files after the message's `id` property. To solve this use

```
<file:outbound-endpoint 
  path="C:\outputfile" 
  outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]"
  responseTimeout="10000"/>
```